# Should unit tests only fail when your application is broken?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

**Question**

Have you ever made changes to your application and everything runs just fine but when you go to run your unit tests all hell breaks lose? That is my specific problem. Would it be fair to say those are not good tests since they fail when my application is working fine? And by 'working' I mean it passes all acceptance tests and each feature works as intended.

**Background**

Most of the time after I've made changes to my application I can run through all the features with no problem, then when I run my unit tests I'll have failures. So there are instances in which I'm spending lots of time updating unit tests that failed for a perfectly working application. My gut tells me that **if your tests fail, when the application passes, then they are useless tests** and all they are doing is alerting the developer to implementation changes they have just made. Is this wrong? Can good tests fail when nothing else in the application in question has failed?

**Example Scenario**

You have unit tests that verify a certain filename is returned such as `fileName.txt`. Everywhere in your code that file is referred to using a constant `IMPORTANT_FILENAME` so changing the file name doesn't affect your application. You decide to change the name of the file from "fileName.txt" to "NewFileName.txt". Your application works fine as it should, but your unit test on `verify(fileName,'fileName.txt')` fails. This is a crude example but I hope you get the point.  The point here is that when I find myself updating unit tests on a working application it seems to me its a red flag that is a bad test. I can't think of any test that fails in a passing application that is a good one. But before I use this as a rule of thumb and start deleting I wanted to get some feedback. Do you agree; unit tests shouldn't fail in a passing application?

**Side-note:** I don't think it matters but I use Java, Junit, and Mockito.

Comment: It depends a lot on context.  Why is your application not failing if a component is failing?

Comment: Yes and yes. Unit tests assert that the API of a "unit" (e.g. a class) works as specified or advertised. You app may not (at the moment) use the API to its full extent, or your system test cases may miss some combination, which is a quite common situation.

Comment: I'll add some examples

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Do your tests always correspond to broken functionality? I'm posting this question because mine don't so I'm tempted to delete any test that fails after a code change when the application passes.

Comment: If the product has changed and the test is no longer applicable, then the test should be improved.

Comment: Umm, `verify(fileName, IMPORTANT_FILENAME)` instead?  (Whatever `verify` is in this context).

Answer (score 3):

In your example, yes, it is a bad test. If the API contract is to return the content of `IMPORTANT_FILENAME`, the test should be testing for that, and not a hardcoded string. 
In general, if a test is broken, the application does not have to necessarily fail. The purpose of the unit test is no so much to ensure the application functionality as it is to enforce the api contract. 
But even if it was the case, simple rules of logic will tell you that "application fails => tests are broken" is *not equivalent* to "tests are broken => application fails".

Comment: Do you have a counter example of a test that fails after a code change, yet the application in question is still fully functional, that you would still view as a relevant test?

Comment: Sure. Consider a test for a function arcLength(double radius, double angle), calculating the length of an circle segment, that is broken, and returns it's second parameter, rather than  a multiple of the two. The application uses that function to compute lengths of various arcs of a circle with radius of 1 inch, and is working fine. The test
`assertEquals(4.0, arcLength(2.0, 2.0))` fails, indicating the function is broken.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. In your example manually testing the application would result in an invalid arcLength. The application would not pass an acceptance test. When I say the application runs I meant it passes its own integration and acceptance tests but its unit tests fail. Such as in the example I gave. The application would pass all business requirements but because the unit tests was locked to a file name it would fail only the unit tests. Is that more clear?

Comment: No, you misunderstood my answer :) Manually testing the application would not result in invalid arc length, because the functionality of application is calculating the length of various arcs of a unit sized circle. It would return correct results to any manual test even if the function, computing length was broken in the way I describe.

Comment: Are you saying the arcLength() is internally broken after a modification so that it performs `return angle` instead of `return radius*angle`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am saying

Comment: Ok. What I'm saying is when a user validates the UI they enter a radius value and an angle value. But because arcLength is broken they see an output which they know is incorrect and so the application will not pass an acceptance test nor would it's unit test.

Comment: You and I are talking about different applications then :) The one I have in mind does not have any way for entering radius. Why would it, if it's sole purpose is measuring arcs of a unit-sized circle?

Comment: Ahaaa!! Your example took me a while to wrap my head around but I get it. If the use for the function is only for unit-sized circles then it would indeed pass an acceptance test but fail a unit test, since the acceptance would only input angle. The unit-size would assume 1 is being multiplied since the output coincidentally would always be just the 2nd parameter. Great example. Would you mind adding your example to your answer before I accept it? Just for the sake of future users.

Answer (score 2):

For me the main purposes of unit tests are

- to give me certainty that a refactoring did not break anything
- a functional change does not have any unwanted side-effects
- safe me the time to test everything manually  i.e. it may be easy to test a certain part of your code with a unit test but it's hard to reach from outside
- often shows flaws in your design (if parts are hard to test automatically)
- enforce programming paradigms

**so if you change something vital to your application (i.e. change functionality) and the unit tests do not fail, you have bad unit tests**. There may be for example a unit test to make sure that all fields are part of equals/hashcode. Or there may be unit tests to asure that certain classes are immutable. Your feature tests may still work, but you introduce unwanted code.

Another real important thing is the **possibility to do TDD (Test Driven Development).**

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests alert you to those times when  you've unwittingly broken some part of the application.  Sometimes, they give you false alarms.  But it's better to have occasional false alarms, than to let bugs into production.

So, yes, it's all right to have unit tests that fail sometimes because you've re-engineered the way your units interact with each other.  It doesn't mean they're bad tests.  It's better to have such tests than not to be alerted when you really do break your application.

Comment: I like the false alarm analogy.

Answer (score 0):

If you make changes to the application without changing any tests, I sure hope at least one test fails!  The tests that verify the piece of code should break in some way.  The rest of the tests should still all pass since they should be using mocks.

So you should have to make at least some minor changes to tests when something has changed.

However, if you are spending too much time having to fix your broken tests, you may have *fragile tests*.  Without seeing the problem code, it's hard to say what to change, but you should apply as many Software Engineering principles and patterns to your test code as your production code.  Try not to have copy and pasted code blocks.  Reuse code via inheritance, helper methods or classes.  That way if you need to make a change that affects many tests, you only have to make the change in one place.

Comment: If you change an implementation within a class, tests need or even must not not fail (e.g. replace one List implementation by another one). If, in your app, you replace a sequential search by a binary search: why should any test fail?

Comment: @laune I guess I'm thinking of more substantial changes than the ones you mention which I agree should not break any good tests

Comment: @dkatzel So to go back to your first sentence, if I change my application and it passes I don't understand why a unit test should fail? That seems like its defeating its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A good test can fail when nothing in the application has failed or could fail.  Generally, unit  tests should cover some aspect of an application that can occur.  However, even if you are able to write test scripts that cover every scenario (a big assumption) it may be that a good unit test is not relevant to any such scenario.  However, who knows whether someone  may alter the application in which such a test would be relevant. Suppose you implement a Map class, but  your application never uses the  remove(Key)  method. You  have implemented a remove(key)  unit  tests however.    Even though your application currently never uses the remove method, someone  may come along at some point and use that method.

Comment: To go back to your first sentence. What's an example of a good test that fails when the application passes after a change is made? I know its a tough question but that's really the basis of mine.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil Perhaps the test tests a corner case, and the corner case was not hit during manual testing.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil  I give you an example of implementing a Map class. The application may always pass if you have of yet used the remove method.  But testing for remove is a good idea, because it is something often used for Maps. So we need to account for future changes as well as current or past changes